# Store and update values in dict on iterating on python

Tags: python, dictionary, nlp

What is the best way in this case, to store for every Speaker the spoken text in a form of a dict or a better option? I want to map every spoken text to each speaker like this try. But the output is not as I expected it.

```
def speaker_texts(cleanedList):

    dictspeaker = {"Speaker": "", "Group": "", "Text": ""}

    pattern_speaker = r"([A-Z]+[a-z]*)([\s]*)(\([A-Z]*\))"

    for sent in cleanedList:
        speaker = re.findall(pattern_speaker, sent)

        for info in speaker:

            dictspeaker.update({"Speaker":info[0], "Group":info[2], "Text": sent})
```

Output:

```
{'Speaker': 'Rische', 'Group': '(KPD)', 'Text': ', Antragsteller: Meine Damen und \nHerren! Anläßlich der Regierungserklärung und \n\n\x0c\n\n30 \n\n(Rische) \nauch in der heutigen Debatte zum Flüchtlings-\nproblem wurden viele Worte über eine sinnvolle, \nden sozialen Belangen entsprechende Verwendung \nöffentlicher Mittel gesprochen. Di e Regierung gab \nin ihrem Programm zu verstehen, daß sie eine ver-\nantwortungsbewußte  Sozialpolitik  durchzuführen \ngedenke. Sie hat die Flüchtlingshilfe, den Woh-\nnungsbau, die Verbe.'}
```

In the file a speaker comes forward several times. I would like to assign the spoken texts to the respective speaker. That is, whenever a speaker occurs, update it in the dictionary so that the new text is added without overwriting the old one.

Or should I create for every Speaker a own dict?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to use namedtuple and create your speaker objects. then append them to a list. Here I write some code to show you how to use nametuple.

```
In [1]: from collections import namedtuple

In [2]: speaker = namedtuple('Speaker', 'speaker goroup text')

In [3]: speaker1 = speaker('Rische', 'KPD', "Antragsteller: Meine 
Damen")

In [4]: speaker1
Out[4]: Speaker(speaker='Rische', goroup='KPD', text='Antragsteller: 
Meine Damen')

In [5]: speaker1.text
Out[5]: 'Antragsteller: Meine Damen'
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. How Can I here map(zip) the Speakers? for e.g., if "Rische" is occured second time. How can I create a tuple with one speaker name and two text sections?

Comment: In nametuple you just define your fild names( speaker, group, text). These field could be anything like dictionaries.

Comment: Can you give an example, how can I trough for loop store the texts of a speaker in a dict on namedtuple? Unfortunalty I cannot find a solution for this.

Comment: you can use a list for your text and append each text in a for loop. or if you need your text to be a dictionary you can just use the update. or you can use a dictionary with a list as value and what a key you desire(for example name of speaker as key). Then you can simply append new text to this value.

Answer (score 0):

In nametuple you just define your field names( speaker, group, text). These fields could be anything like dictionaries.

```
In [19]: speaker = namedtuple('Speaker', 'speaker goroup text')

In [20]: text = {'a':1, 'b':2}

In [21]: speaker1 = speaker('Rische','KPD',text)

In [22]: speaker1
Out[22]: Speaker(speaker='Rische', goroup='KPD', text={'b': 2, 'a': 1})
```